# Connecting to database with ODBC results in warnings and nothing printed

Tags: php, odbc

I am trying to use ODBC with php and I seem to be having some problems. This is my code:

```
<?php
    $connect = odbc_connect("digitallibrary", "root", "");
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM books";
    $result = odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
    echo $result;

    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
        $name = odbc_result($result, "name");
        print("$name\n");
    }
    odbc_close($connect);
    ?>
```

I have also installed mysql odbc connector and added this system DSN:
Datasource Name : digitallibrary
TCP/IP Server: localhost Port 80
user: root
database:digitallibrary

When I run my code I get this warnings but nothing printed:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application, SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\DigitalLibrary\index.php on line 9
>
> Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\DigitalLibrary\index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\DigitalLibrary\index.php on
>   line 14
>
> Warning: odbc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\DigitalLibrary\index.php on
>   line 18

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, You are attempting to use a 64 bit application with a 32 bit ODBC driver or vice versa. You should check that *what are you using the PHP application 64 bit or 32 bit*. After that you have to start the correct ODBC administrator. There are 2 types which are `32 bit` and and `64 bit`.

> If you are using 64 bit ODBC administrator: It is in Adminstrative tools, control panel
>
> If you are using 32 bit ODBC administrator: You should go into the path `%windir\syswow64\odbcad32.exe.`

When you have set the right ODBC administrator. You will also need to create the system DSN. If you cannot find the MS Access driver in the administrator you'll need to download one for that architecture.

**EDIT** : you can download the 32 bit from [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Later versions of Windows have both 64-bit and 32-bit Data Source administrator in the Control Panel / Admin Tools.

Comment: Can both 64-bit and 32-bit odbc drivers run at the same time on the same server? we have a Win Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Would there be no problem if i ADD another ODBC driver (a 32bit version to cater my 32bit application) to a server with an existing 64bit version (which some other application maybe using the 64bit)? Would it not create confilict to other applications? I am worried that if I install a 32bit version that it may affect the existing and running applications on the server