# odbc_exec() and odbc_fetch_row() error

Tags: php, odbc

I'm getting 2 painfully annoying errors:

> PHP Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt, SQL state S1000 in SQL ExecDirect in blahblah on Line 22
>
> PHP Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

BUT, then it goes ahead and lists everything that I'm looking for in that column. I really just need to know how to clean up my results so that I can then start sifting through them.

```
$conn =     odbc_pconnect("$driver;Server=$server;Database=$database;MARS_Connection=yes",     $user, $password);
if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection established.";
} else{
    die("Connection could not be established.");
}
$sql = 'SELECT t_item FROM erplnfp7.twhinr140600';
$outval = odbc_columns($conn, "erplnfp7", "%", "twhinr140600", "%");
$pages = array();
while (odbc_fetch_into($outval, $pages)) {
    echo $pages[3] . PHP_EOL;
    $q = 'SELECT t_item FROM twhinr140600'; 
    $cur = odbc_exec($conn,$q); 
    while(odbc_fetch_row($cur)){ 
        $CommSettings = odbc_result($cur,'t_item'); 
        echo "$CommSettings"; 
    }
}


odbc_close($conn);
```

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT t_item FROM twhinr140600` That query failed

Comment: May this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071940/connecting-to-database-with-odbc-results-in-warnnings-and-notjing-printed

Comment: Does it raise the error already on the first iteration in the while-loop, or does the error occur in the 2nd run of the loop? If it raises on the 2nd iteration, try adding a call to `odbc_free_result($cur)` before the next run of the loop starts.

Comment: It happens from the first iteration. In fact, it adds another warning: "PHP Warning: odbc_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .... on line 29." I also took out the "erplnfp7.twhinr140600" and just left it as the table name: twhinr140600. Something is working, it gives me what I'm looking for, I just don't understand why I keep getting warnings.

Comment: @RaviHirani I did have a look at that link, and all of it is set up correctly. I'm still not sure.